# What does "play" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "step/strategy"? I used this link: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/play_2

> "GIC Pte, the Swiss bank's largest shareholder, said on Tuesday that it was paring its 5.1 percent stake to 2.7 percent. When GIC announced in December 2007 that it would buy UBS convertible bonds for 11 billion Swiss francs -- roughly $10 billion at the time -- the bank had just written down U.S. subprime investments by an equal amount. GIC thought UBS was ahead of the curve in recognizing subprime losses, and a long-term interest would be a good **play** on the "high growth potential" for wealth management in Asia."

Source: https://www.bloomberg.com/gadfly/articles/2017-05-16/hna-can-avoid-singapore-s-ubs-sour-grapes

Comment: Yes, it means *strategy* there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct and it does mean "strategy", similar to #4 in the Oxford dictionary you link:

> *4. (North American English) an action or move in a game*

In particular the sport of American Football is broken up into *plays*, run one at a time.  Each of these is strategically chosen and potentially countered with a *play* by the opposing team.  So when discussing football it's common to hear expressions like:

> What *play* should they *run* here?
>
> Oh, that was a smart *play*!
>
> That coach needs to find something else to run in his *playbook* or he's going to lose.

In the same way you can reference *any* strategic move as a "play", as if it was part of a larger game that you intend to win.